# search live Ajax in PHP CI doesnt print the result

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, codeigniter

I am wondering why in this code, when I type the names in input,There is no result. I also see the error Json parser in my console :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data
```

The problem can be from json file which is sent by model and can not be retrieved with view!or something else from json!

view:index.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#search").keyup(function(){
        if($("#search").val().length>3){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/phpAmir_contract/index.php/employee",
            cache: false,               
            data:'search='+$("#search").val(),
            success: function(response){
                $('#finalResult').html("");
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                if(obj.length>0){
                    try{
                        var items=[];   
                        $.each(obj, function(i,val){                                            
                            items.push($('<li/>').text(val.FIRST_NAME + " " + val.LAST_NAME));
                        }); 
                        $('#finalResult').append.apply($('#finalResult'), items);
                    }catch(e) {     
                        alert('Exception while request..');
                    }       
                }else{
                    $('#finalResult').html($('<li/>').text("No Data Found"));       
                }       

            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
        });
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<p>Note:- Please start typing surname as "Chavan", "Patil"</p>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
<ul id="finalResult"></ul>
</div>
</body>
```

controller :

```
class Employee extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('EmployeeModel');
    }

    public function index(){
        $search=  $this->input->post('search');
        $query = $this->EmployeeModel->getEmployee($search);
    //    $this->load->view('index',$query);
        echo json_encode ($query);  

    }
```

And the model:

```
class EmployeeModel extends CI_Model {

     function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct(); 
  }
    function getEmployee($search){    
        $this->db->select("EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME");
        $whereCondition = array('LAST_NAME' =>$search);
        $this->db->where($whereCondition);
        $this->db->from('trn_employee');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result(); 
                }
}
```

This is my result, instead of having json results in input box when user type a char, I see them all dumped in page!

[image]

Comment: What does the JSON that is output to the browser look like.  It sounds like it is malformed. I would think you either need the view to render the JSON or echo the JSON straight from controller, not do both.

Comment: @MikeBrant when I removed the view as I edited here, I see the blank page.

Comment: It seems pretty clear you problem is that somehwere in your code, you are doing a `var_dump()` which is messing up your JSON output.  I also don't understand why you would have a form generated by the script that is generating the JSON output.  The page you form is in and the backend script that serves JSON should not be the same.

Answer (score -1):

Then start from the beginning: Is your query right? Do you have datas in your controller and how is the JSON looking?

Comment: I see all json out puts dumping in my page instead having them inside the box when user type a char!

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be a comment.

Answer (score -2):

Why are you loading a view in your controller? Try to remove the line and just output the json.

Comment: when I remove it, I see the blank page!

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be a comment.